# Ubuntu 20.04 wifi driver not compatible with Intel

Tags: drivers, wireless, network-manager, 21.04

My wifi keeps logging out after X minutes, depends, if I start downloading it's instant.

I have to turn OFF Airplan mode and ON, it works instantly, then wait ~3 minutes again it turns off. Tried all the things like disable IPV6 .... like 10 first pages of google to fix this, it didn't work. I think the problem is with the driver. Since It says "I don't use proprietary drivers"

```
$uname -a:
Linux quinella 5.11.0-25-generic #27-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 9 23:06:29 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$lspci:
08:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.04
Release:    21.04
Codename:   hirsute
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `iwconfig` as it sounds like a power management issue

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.